# Conflict manual and automatic slideshow

Tags: slideshow

I have problems with manual and automatic slideshow. I can't find a solution how to reset the setInterval inside the function init_slideshow if the button to the manual slideshow is pressed.
js code:

```
function iterator(a) {
    if (!Array.isArray(a)) {
        return;
    }
    
    let nextIndex = 0;
    return function next(b) {
        if (b == undefined) {
            if (nextIndex == a.length) {
                throw "error";
            } else {
            return a[nextIndex++];  
            }

        }   else if(Array.isArray(b)) {
            a = b;
            nextIndex = 0;
            return next;
            // return iterator(b);
        } else {
            return nextIndex+= b;
        }
    }
    
    
}

function init_slideshow(image_urls, dom, automatic = false, delay = 3000)
{   
    let v = iterator(image_urls);
    function slideshow() {
        let img = "";
        try {
            img = v();
        } catch {
            v(image_urls);
            img = v();
        }
        dom.src = img;
    }
    slideshow();
    let t = setInterval(slideshow,delay);
    if (automatic) {
        return t; 
    } else { 
        return slideshow;
    }
}
```